# How can I read all contacts in Android 1.5 mobile?

Tags: android

I want to be able read all contacts in Android mobile version 1.5.

Please help me. list readble contant and example please thanks in advance

Comment: I'm finding that quite difficult to understand. What exactly are you trying to do? What problems have you had?

Answer (score 1):

For a ListActivity you can have

```
Cursor C = getContentResolver().query(People.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
startManagingCursor(C);

String[] columns = new String[] {People.NAME};
int[] names = new int[] {R.id.row_entry};

mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.mycontacts, C, columns, names);
setListAdapter(mAdapter);
```